# Does NginX for Windows support IPv6?

Tags: windows, nginx, ipv6

I work with:

- NginX (version 1.17.9)
- on Windows Server 2016.

NginX works fine with IPv4 IP adresses, but it does not work with IPv6 IP addresses. When I type

```
nginx -V
```

from the dos command prompt, I see the following listing:

```
C:\nginx1_17\nginx-1.17.9>nginx -V

nginx version: nginx/1.17.9
built by cl 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-cc=cl --builddir=objs.msvc8 --with-debug --prefix= --conf-path=conf/nginx.conf --pid-path=logs/nginx.pid --http-log-path=logs/access.log --error-log-path=logs/error.log --sbin-path=nginx.exe --http-client-body-temp-path=temp/client_body_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=temp/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=temp/fastcgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=temp/scgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=temp/uwsgi_temp --with-cc-opt=-DFD_SETSIZE=1024 --with-pcre=objs.msvc8/lib/pcre-8.44 --with-zlib=objs.msvc8/lib/zlib-1.2.11 --with-http_v2_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-mail --with-stream --with-openssl=objs.msvc8/lib/openssl-1.1.1d --with-openssl-opt='no-asm no-tests -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501' --with-http_ssl_module --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_module
```

In the configuration settings above, I don't see the NginX IPv6 support statement: `with-ipv6`.

in the nginx.conf file the following statements works fine:

```
server{
        #IPv4
        listen 443 ssl; 
        server_name  mywebsite.com;
        {
        location /
         root html;
         index index.html;
         }
      }
```

When I change it to:

```
server{
        #IPv6
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        server_name  mywebsite.com;
        {
        location /
         root html;
         index index.html;
         }
      }
```

it does NOT work anymore.

I've already added a AAAA record for the IPv6 address in my domain. This is confirmed by the internet domain check at:

https://ip6.nl/

My questions:

1. Does NginX for Windows support IPv6?
2. How to enable IPv6 support in NginX for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. I discovered my IPv6 address was not accessible for 2 reasons:

- My firewall did not let pass IPv6 requests. I added a rule for the
  IPv6 adresses: I used ::/0 (= IPv6 equivalent of 0.0.0.0/0)
- My IPv6 was not reacheable from the internet,
  because the gateway and the DNS were not properly configured. I discovered this by testing my IP from the server at: http://whatismyip.com

So, the answer to the question: 'does NginX for Windows supports IPv6' is yes!